# Syntax error found int expecting ; C ICC12 Compiler

Tags: c, compiler-construction, port

I have the following code

```
#include <hcs12dp256.h>

void spinloop(int spins)
{
 for (int i=0; i<spins; i++)
 {
  i ++;
 }
}

void main(void)
{
 DDRK = DDRK & 0x0F;
 PORTK = PORTK & 0x00;

 PORTK = PORTK | 0x01;
 PORTK = PORTK | 0x02;

 spinloop(100000);

 PORTK = PORTK & 0x0C;
 PORTK = PORTK | 0x03;
 PORTK = PORTK | 0x04;
}
```

When I go to compile it I'm getting loads of errors, mainly around the for loop. I'm getting the following error on line 5

```
Syntax error found int expecting ;
```

followed by

```
Syntax error found int expecting )
Skipping int
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue is, I'm fairly new to this coding so I may simply be missing something simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
for (int i=0; i<spins; i++)
```

with

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<spins; i++)
```

Your compiler probably doesn't support C99.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
for (int i=0; i<spins; i++)
```

use

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<spins; i++)
```

Note- In c we cannot define variable inside for loop

Comment: Actually we can define variables inside loops in C99 and later, but the statement is correct for C before C99, and it's likely the source of the error at hand.

Comment: Yes But By default gcc is in C90/C89 mode.That's why its not working.
Unless we tell compiler to run on C99 mode,It will throw this error.